# The fields after using the lateral view expand cannot be inserted into the new table

Tags: sql

```
insert overwrite table manual_goodsanalysistask_arrangedata partition(kind)
select
    taskid,
    sellernick,
    buyernicktype,
    memberlevel,
    statisticstype
    starttime,
    endtime,
    categorytype,
    tradetype,
    filtertype,
    tasktype,
    goodstype,
    b as sku,
    kind
from manual_goodsanalysistask_arrangedata
lateral view explode(split(sku,',')) a as b
where kind = 30;
```

Comment: please tag your dbms

Comment: Maxcompute(odps)